# Issue with removeTarget leftBarButtonItem - may not respond

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to swop the action for a leftBarButtonItem

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIBarButtonItem *theButton = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

    // 'UIBarButtonItem' may not respond to 'removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:'
    [theButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(revealToggle:)          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // 'UIBarButtonItem' may not respond to 'removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:'
    [theButton addTarget:self    action:@selector(closeToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // BUT THIS DOES WORK
    [theButton.target performSelector:theButton.action];

}
```

According to what I've read it should work - what am I doing wrong?

Actually this is a work around to something more complicated that I don't understand.

I want to send a message from the current UIViewController that's within the UINavigation Controller.

The UINavigationController has this button

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnmenu.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
```

which works fine. What I really what to do is

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController closeToggle];
```

from within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function, which fails, but I managed to achieve the same effect with [theButton.target performSelector:theButton.action]

Comment: is there any need to remove the target of that particular button... just add the another target it will override it.

Comment: @Abhishek Everytime I've read says you have to remove the old one first, and besides the addTarget line is still failing regardless of the removeTarget line

Comment: but i don't think so u just add second one and try it..

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` does not descend from a `UIControl`. So `addTarget:` and `removeTarget` do not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, `UIBarButtonItem` does not inherit `UIControl` methods, thus your warnings for `addTarget` and `removeTarget`. Instead what you do is directly assign a new `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnmenu.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                     target:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(clearToggle)];
```

Also, notice the difference in your defined selector for the targeted `UIBarButtonItem` **closeToggle:** . But what you said you want to do is send a message to the parent controller of, **closeToggle**. The colon there is quite different as one expects a parameter. Performing an action on `closeToggle:` if your method is `closeToggle` will result in a crash, and vice versa.

```
-(void)closeToggle:(id)sender // your UIBarButtonItem action.
-(void)closeToggle            // which is, [self.navigationController.parentViewController closeToggle];
```

Decide what method it is you want and follow the above signing of a new `UIBarButtonItem`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right about closeToggle:(id)sender, I'd already discovered that, trying you're code now. Do you know how the call the leftBarButtonItem's action directly from a button in the UIViewController?

Comment: You've already done this in your code, `[theButton.target performSelector:theButton.action];`. Instead of `theButton.target` use `[self performSelector:theButton.action]`, or wherever the target is..

Comment: You code works perfectly (as long as I restore the original action before pushing another view onto the stack) Thank you! Will accept it in a minute... but do you know how to write [self.navigationController.parentViewController closeToggle] which works in theory from within the UINavigationController so it works from with the UIViewController ?

Comment: Great. In your `UIViewController` cast a `UIBarButtonItem` and retrieve the selector from it. Like you have in your code already, and perform that action from another button event.

Comment: The problem is that self.navigationController.parentViewController does not reach the intended controller from within the UIViewController that is within the UINavigationController. I think I need  something like self.myViewController.navigationController.parentViewController ?

Comment: Is this `UIViewController` you're wanting to send the method from is in the `UINavigationController` stack?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12568/discussion-between-julianb-and-skram)